# Opshub Key is Not Working

Tags: opshub

My opshub migration tool key is not working.

The installation is not emailing me a new key and older ones I have in email do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, contact to ovsmu@opshub.com, they will send key by validating your email id.

Comment: Thanks. I did that first and it said to post it here.  I thought it was usual but I followed protocol.